# How do I compute and store a double value in c++ with 6 digits or higher precision?

Tags: c++, double, precision

The code goes as following, I need to store a long double variable wt and subsequently edl[x].w as 6 precision value , Thanks in advance.

```
   for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
        edl[x].a=i;
        edl[x].b=j;
        long double wt =sqrt(  pow(pts[i].x-pts[j].x,2)+pow(pts[i].y-pts[j].y,2)  );
        edl[x].w=wt;    
        x+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `double` is stored internally with 53 bits of mantissa for your precision needs.  Are you talking about how to *display* the variable with more than 6 digits of precision?

Comment: You should search your favorite C++ reference for the I/O manipulator, `set_precision`.

Comment: Also, multiplying variables (squaring) is more efficient that calling `pow(x,2)`.  Some compilers may recognize this pattern on higher optimization levels.  At the minimum, you are removing the overhead of function call and return.

Comment: No I don't want to display it, I want to store it for further computations with 6 digits as I said.

Comment: This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) says that the IEEE floating point format has a least 15 digits of precision.  I did a Google search for "C++ double digits of precision" and most of the articles are stating that the `double` type has 15 digits of precision.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a `long double` will have more digits of precision, you can guarantee that it will have at least the same precision as a `double`.  On some platforms, [the `long double` type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) can occupy 80 bits, which may give more than 15 digits of precision.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you need quite a few more digits to store double without loss of precision

Comment: Side note: Be absolutely certain that `for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++)` is what you want. Using origin one arrays in C++ often ends poorly.

Comment: Reminder:  The `pow` and `sqrt` functions may reduce your precision, depending on how they are implemented.

Comment: For loop statement is not a problem at all I declared that array for n+1 elements.

Comment: I need sqrt function for now and pow could be replaced but still how do increase the storing precision?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews told you to replace `pow(x,2)` with `x * x`

Comment: ***how do increase the storing precision?*** You can't, you can only store what is in the `double` or `long  double`. When you visualize it is where you specify how many digits to print from what is stored in the variable. If you save it to a file as text you are visualizing it.

Comment: Your compiler may support floating point variables or formats that have more than 64 bits.  You'll have to check the compiler documentation.  Also, there is no guarantee that all the math functions will support it.

Comment: If you *really* need precision, you should switch over to Fixed Point Notation.  Fixed point notation uses integers.  Many integer types have over 64 bits of precision.  For example with metric length, you would use millimeters as the unit instead of meters.  Many embedded systems use 64-bit integers to represent nano seconds instead of floating point for seconds.

Comment: Really appreciate your help guys , thanks a lot.